# How to change text of div which already contains other DOM elements?

Tags: jquery, html, dom

In my page I have many DIV and P tags, and I want to change the text of all these tags to 'Hi' ( any arbitrary word ). All I can think of is:

```
$('div, p').not('.btn').each ( function() {

      var oT = $(this).text();
      $(this).text ( 'hi ' + oT );
  });
```

---

```
 <div class='btn'>Change All Text</div>

       <div id='container1'>
       main content
       <div>
         div > div
         <p>
           div > div > p
         </p>
       </div>

       <p>div > p </p>
       <p>div > p </p>

  </div>

  <p>
    p
  </p>

  <p>P
  </p>
```

See: http://jsbin.com/usepuq/

Now, instead of changing text of all Divs what it is doing is: it is changing the text of the parent object. And as soon as it change the parent object's text, automatically and obviously all children vanish. So we left with just one Div and two P tags.

Another thing I could do is:

```
 var oT = $(this).html();
 $(this).html ( 'hi ' + oT );
```

This somehow changes the text of the parent objects and children remains intact.

So the thing is how can we change the text of all DIV and P tags. There is no restriction of nesting depth.

**P.S.** This is not a real problem, I am just trying to see if it can be accomplished or not.

Comment: I think the code is doing just what you are asking it to do. Unless you target the only the innermost <div>s and <p>s, it will continue to behave as such since as it is, it replaces even the content of the parent <div>s

Comment: @JohnGathogo That's right. How to change the text of each and every DIV and P tags text? Thats the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried this?

```
$('.btn').click ( function () {
  $('div, p').not('.btn').each ( function() {

      $(this).prepend('hi');

  });
});
```

example: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c5FGp/)

Comment: Though it is not changing(replacing) the text of the tags, it is just prepending. But still acceptable. Please change your answer if you can still make it to completely `replace` the text instead of `prepend`.